# Grammatical relation of "time"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> Throughout the history of Europe, from the beginnings of heraldry up
>   to our time, national frontiers have shifted ***time*** and again, often as
>   the result of war, but also for example through marriage or
>   inheritance. (Volborth, Carl Alexander von., Heraldry of The World, pp177,178)

What is the grammatical relation of "time" in above sentence? Does it mean "frequently" in here?

Comment: It's just a shortening of the somewhat verbose ["time and time again"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22time+and+time+again%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (at one time/occasion, then another, then by implication possibly many more times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *time* in this context should be read as part of the adverbial phrase *time and again*, which does indeed mean *frequently*.